# Does PDF version 2.0 support image transparency with Lualatex?

Tags: graphics, luatex, pdf, transparency

I tried to insert an image (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_logo#/media/File:Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg)) with transparency like the one below in a PDF version 2.0.

[image]

The problem is that the transparency of the image in question is not well managed. Without explicitly using PDF version 2.0, there is no particular problem. Here is an illustration of the problem (left PDF 1.5, right PDF 2.0):

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfvariable majorversion 2 % PDF version 2.0
\pdfvariable minorversion 0
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image.png}
\end{document}
```

Is PDF version 2.0 and image transparency not supported by LuaLaTeX?

The `log` file:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (MiKTeX 22.1) (format=lualatex 2022.2.22)  26 FEB 2022 22:30
 system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2021-05-21 3.18 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2021-05-20.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/f
ontloader-2021-05-20.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.116
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 4
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2022-02-05>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' at position 1 in `input_level_string'.
(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen137
)
(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.c
fg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.

(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2021/06/01 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen138
\Gin@req@width=\dimen139
)
(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-lua
tex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count191
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.

(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count192
\scratchdimen=\dimen140
\scratchbox=\box51
\nofMPsegments=\count193
\nofMParguments=\count194
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count195
\MPscratchDim=\dimen141
\MPnumerator=\count196
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count197
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
)
(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-b
ase.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/epstopdf-sys.c
fg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
<image.png, id=1, 317.185pt x 317.185pt>
File: image.png Graphic file (type png)
<use image.png>
Package luatex.def Info: image.png  used on input line 6.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: 317.1842pt x 317.1842pt.
 [1

{C:/Users/intri/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}<./image.png>]
 (./test.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1358 strings out of 477794
 100000,383344 words of node,token memory allocated
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:35,3:4,4:1,5:23,6:2,7:34,9:38
 22058 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 55i,5n,59p,189b,123s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<//?/c:/users/intri/appdata/local/programs/miktex/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmrom
an10-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 15116 bytes).

PDF statistics: 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: without the real image it is not possible to test your issue. Also you should show your log file so that one can see which version you are using.

Comment: This might also be a viewer problem if the viewer doesn't correctly handle PDF 2.0. Have you tried different viewers?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have the same problem with all tested images (PNG) with transparency, so I guess the problem is not the images themselves. I added the log file to my post.

Comment: @HenriMenke I tested with Adobe Reader (latest version) as well as with the viewers integrated in Texmaker and Google Chrome.

Comment: make one image available.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited my post. I took as an example the logo of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_logo#/media/File:Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg) (PNG format).

Comment: well I can confirm the bug, but it works again with a experimental luatex 1.14.0  development id 7469 which I have here, so I think the bug has been be resolved.

Comment: actually I reported that last year: https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2021-June/007546.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your answer, I will wait for the next release.